# Have you seen this line core.apexpages.el.adapters.AggregateResultELAdapter@?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, map, collection

I want to display in a VisualForce Page a map like this, `Map<Integer, List<aggregateResult>>`. But the map only shows "core.apexpages.el.adapters.AggregateResultELAdapter@3482c248".

Does anybody know what this line means?

Here is part of the extension:

```
public Map<Integer, List<aggregateResult>> slpVSC = new Map<Integer, List<aggregateResult>>();
    public Map<Integer, List<aggregateResult>> getSlp() {
      return slpVSC;
    }

    // Pruebas 
    public void VSC() {

      //get{
          Map<Integer, aggregateResult> tByMonth = new Map<Integer, aggregateResult>(); 

          for (aggregateResult o: [Select CALENDAR_MONTH(Fecha_de_Solicitud_de_Compra__c) month_number, COUNT(Id) num_offer,
                                    Fraccionamiento__r.Name name_fracc 
                                    From pba__Offer__c 
                                    Where CALENDAR_YEAR(Fecha_de_Solicitud_de_Compra__c) = 2014
                                    And Fraccionamiento__r.Name IN ('Something','Something')
                                    Group By CALENDAR_MONTH(Fecha_de_Solicitud_de_Compra__c),Fraccionamiento__r.Name 
                                    Order By CALENDAR_MONTH(Fecha_de_Solicitud_de_Compra__c)]) {

                    Integer mes = (Integer)o.get('month_number');
                    Integer cOffer = (Integer)o.get('num_offer');
                    String name = (String)o.get('name_fracc');
                    Integer fId = stdCtrl.nFracc.get(name);

                    if (slpVSC.containsKey(fId)) {
                         slpVSC.get(fId).add(o);
                    }  else {
                         slpVSC.put(fId, new List<aggregateResult>{o});
                    }        


          }
           System.debug('Consolidado >>>'+slpVSC);
          //return tByMonth;
      //}
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code where you build the map. I am suspecting you are adding sobject as a key which is being translated as you see

Comment: how are you accessing your map in your visualforce page?

Comment: I am accessing this way                              `<apex:repeat value="{!Slp}" var="mes">
       {!Slp[mes]}
</apex:repeat>`

Comment: I do not think you can reference aggregateresults directly in a vf page, you might need a wrapper class ( or) googling around looks like you can serialize the results too and reference in the vf page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is exposing some internal implementation detail; you can interpret it as saying that there is something wrong with the Visualforce expression.

As I understand Visualforce, `mes` will be each of the key values of the map and so `Slp[mes]` will be a `List<aggregateResult>` where an `AggregateResult` has a map-like interface. (I'm assuming this can be directly referenced in the page but that may not be the case.)

So if this data structure is correct, you will need something like this to present it:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Slp}" var="mes">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Slp[mes]" var="ar">
        {!mes} {!ar['month_number']} {!ar['num_offer']}
        <br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```